# How to run Swagger command in CLI

Tags: node.js, command, command-line-interface, swagger

I am following one article related to a Swagger.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node

*Section: Your swagger API in five steps*

I install Swagger with npm using -g command. However, I am not able to fire command related to Swagger. It shows me error saying ***'swagger' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***

Comment: Due to not having admin rights, I was facing this problem. Hence, closing it.

Comment: Though I have set path variable having 'c:/.../Roaming/npm', I was unable to fire swagger commands. Then I am manually setting path 'set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\...\Roaming\npm" ' whenever i open cmd.